# Are EventCounters the standard way to expose metrics from .NET libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, open-telemetry

Since .NET Core 3, the .NET SDK exposes metrics through the [EventCounters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/event-counters). It is also possible to implement your own EventCounter. So let's assume I'm developing a memcache client in .NET, would it make sense to expose get/set metrics through EventCounters? Also, I noticed that none of the [Well-known EventCounters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/available-counters) use dynamic metric names such as `memcache-{myMemcacheClusterName}-gets`. Is it not recommended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the release of .NET 6, [System.Diagnostics.Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.metrics), an official .NET implementation of the [OpenTelemetry Metrics API](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/metrics/api.md) is included.

In this conversation [dotnet/designs/pull/211](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/211/files#r637622786) we can see that Metrics is now preferred over EventCounters.

> We'll recommend using Metrics moving forward but we are not deprecating the Event counters in this release at least.

Note that [System.Diagnostics.Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.metrics) is available for .NET < 6 through the Nuget [System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource >= 6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19). Here is an example: [verdie-g/modern-caching/src/ModernCaching/Instrumentation/OpenTelemetryCacheMetrics.cs](https://github.com/verdie-g/modern-caching/blob/b983c0bc66ce039ef47d45ca8060e6b89455baff/src/ModernCaching/Instrumentation/OpenTelemetryCacheMetrics.cs).

Answer (score 1):

> So let's assume I'm developing a memcache client in .NET, would it make sense to expose get/set metrics through EventCounters?

Sure, of course you could go for something like [App Metrics](https://www.app-metrics.io/) but the nice thing about EventCounters is that it is part of the .Net Framework so no external dependencies are required. Something that is attractive when writing a library.

> Also, I noticed that none of the Well-known EventCounters use dynamic metric names such as memcache-{myMemcacheClusterName}-gets. Is it not recommended?

Dynamic counters are hard to discover and to document (what possible values are there). It used to be the only way to include additional information though. That is, until the introduction of metadata. Nowadays you can add additional information to the counters using [AddMetadata()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.diagnosticcounter.addmetadata?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Tracing_DiagnosticCounter_AddMetadata_System_String_System_String_):

```cs
EventCounter someCounter = new EventCounter(nameof(someCounter), this);
someCounter.AddMetadata("Environment", "Production");
someCounter.AddMetadata("SomeKey", "SomeValue");
```

Comment: I didn't know about Metadata, that's perfect 